# Where is kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave documented?

Tags: ios, security, keychain

I'm banging my head trying to generate a private-public key pair with `kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave` so that the private key is generated in the secure enclave.

Where is `kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave` documented? Below is my code, which fails with status code -50.

```
- (void)generateKeyPair {
    const UInt8 publicTagString[] = "public";
    const UInt8 privateTagString[] = "private";

    publicTag = CFDataCreate(0, publicTagString, sizeof(publicTagString));
    privateTag = CFDataCreate(0, privateTagString, sizeof(privateTagString));

    CFMutableDictionaryRef publicAttr = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL, NULL);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(publicAttr, kSecAttrApplicationTag, publicTag);
    // CFDictionaryAddValue(publicAttr, kSecAttrIsPermanent, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(publicAttr, kSecAttrCanEncrypt, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(publicAttr, kSecAttrCanDecrypt, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(publicAttr, kSecAttrCanDerive, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(publicAttr, kSecAttrCanSign, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(publicAttr, kSecAttrCanVerify, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(publicAttr, kSecAttrCanUnwrap, kCFBooleanFalse);

    CFMutableDictionaryRef privateAttr = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL, NULL);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(privateAttr, kSecAttrApplicationTag, privateTag);
    // CFDictionaryAddValue(privateAttr, kSecAttrIsPermanent, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(privateAttr, kSecAttrCanEncrypt, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(privateAttr, kSecAttrCanDecrypt, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(privateAttr, kSecAttrCanDerive, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(privateAttr, kSecAttrCanSign, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(privateAttr, kSecAttrCanVerify, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(privateAttr, kSecAttrCanUnwrap, kCFBooleanFalse);

    const void* parameterKeys[] = {
        kSecAttrKeyType,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits,
        kSecAttrTokenID,
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs
    };

    int intKeySize = 512;
    CFNumberRef keySize = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &intKeySize);

    const void* parameterValues[] = {
        kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        keySize,
        kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
        publicAttr,
        privateAttr
    };

    CFDictionaryRef parameters = CFDictionaryCreate(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        parameterKeys,
        parameterValues,
        5, // ??? Make this programmatic
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    OSStatus status = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &publicKey, &privateKey);

    if(status != errSecSuccess) {
        [self logError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SecKeyGeneratePair status %d", (int)status] :nil];
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Things work properly with RSA, but then kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave and kSecAccessControlPrivateKeyUsage can't be specified." Taken from [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8030). Can't we have RSA pairs with kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave then? Where is that documented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you are getting, `-50`, indicates a parameter error. A parameter you are passing to the function is incorrect or inappropriate for the operation. If you look at the `SecItem` header or the you will see:

> kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave Specifies well-known identifier of the
>            token implemented using device's Secure Enclave. The only keychain items
>            supported by the Secure Enclave token are 256-bit elliptic curve keys
>            (kSecAttrKeyTypeEC).  Keys must be generated on the secure enclave using
>            SecKeyGenerateKeyPair call with kSecAttrTokenID set to
>            kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave in the parameters dictionary, it is not
>            possible to import pregenerated keys to kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave token.

RSA is not currently a supported cipher when generating a private key in the secure enclave. Switch to a 256 bit EC key.

This was covered in the WWDC 2015 session 706 [Security And Your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-706/). The Apple sample project "KeychainTouchID" shows the correct parameters for generating and using a key using the secure enclave.

Comment: Update: as of iOS 10+ [`kSecAttrKeyTypeEC`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattrkeytypeec?language=objc) is deprecated in favor of [`kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattrkeytypeecsecprimerandom?language=objc).